# Get Max record in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, max

I have a scenario where I would love to return 3 columns by getting the max record in SQL Server. like below

```
   ID   PID     PDATE                       Satus    CANUMBERS
   1    PS1     2015-08-05 12:20:49.627 0   1        CAA0322
   2    PS2     2015-08-06 04:05:52.053 0   1        CAA0322
   3    PS2     2015-08-07 07:17:32.653 1   1        CAA0322
```

in this case what am looking for is getting max `PDate` of each `PID`, like the last record of pid entered at all times.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(ID), PID, PDATE   
FROM 
    TABLE1
GROUP BY 
    PID, PDATE  ...
```

The problem with grouping the pdate, it returns all the records. i only want the max pdate for each PID like

```
1    PS1        2015-08-05 12:20:49.627 0   1        CAA0322
3    PS2        2015-08-07 07:17:32.653 1   1        CAA0322
```

any help please

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a CTE with a `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function - something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, PID, PDATE, Satus, CANUMERS,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY PDATE DESC)
    FROM
        dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT
    ID, PID, PDATE, Satus, CANUMERS
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
```

The `PARTITION BY` clause partitions your data by the column `PID` and then numbers each partition beginning from 1 - so the row with `RowNum = 1` is the **most recent** row (ordered by `PDATE` descending - newest first) for each `PID`

Comment: is it possible to join this whole statement to another table lets say table2 has PID,Books,Author   ... and i want to get Books,Author records by joining the PID of the above statement?

Comment: @Bels: yes sure - just add an `INNER JOIN` to the `SELECT .. FROM CTE....` - it's just a regular T-SQL statement, nothing magic or crazy about it...

Answer (score 2):

Another, potentially easier example than CTE and window functions, would be to just join your max grouping in a subquery, returning only the matching rows, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(ID) ID, MAX(PDATE) PDATE, PID -- Listing PID here is unnecessary, but makes the query easier to understand
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY PID) SRC 
        ON SRC.ID = T1.ID AND SRC.PDATE = T1.PDATE
```

See it in action in SQLFiddle, [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25725/1/0).

But, what if there are two records tied for max date? Do you want just the one (ie, the latest ID), or ALL records tied for max?

If you want the ties as well, change the select to this instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(PDATE) PDATE, PID
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY PID) SRC 
        ON SRC.PDATE = T1.PDATE AND SRC.PID = T1.PID
```

Comment: There is a different output than the CTE if you happen to have equal dates..

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` Function to achieve the Output:

```
 create table maxrecord
   (
   id int,
   PID varchar(10),
   pdate datetime,
   statuss int,
   CANUMBERS varchar(10))


   insert into maxrecord values(1,'PS1','2015-08-05 12:20:49.627',1,'CAA0322'),
                               (2,'PS2','2015-08-06 04:05:52.053',1,'CAA0322'),
                               (3,'PS2','2015-08-07 07:17:32.653',1,'CAA0322')



;WITH CTE as
(
select row_number() over (partition by PID order by PDATE DESC) as ROWNUM ,* from maxrecord
)
select  id ,
       PID ,
      pdate,
   statuss ,
  CANUMBERS 
   from CTE where ROWNUM=1
```